# Splitting a list into a pairs in Python

Tags: python, list

This is a homework.
I'm not looking for answers, just a nudge into the right direction.

Given a list:

```
['The Boy','1:34','Let go','4:21','Wherever to', '5:30']
```

I want to be able to sort the list by pairs:

```
[['The Boy','1:34']['Let go','4:21']['Wherever to', '5:30']]
```

Comment: Are you assured of having an even number of elements in the list? If not, what do you want to do with the odd one out?

Comment: I'm assured that its going to be an even amount in the list.

Comment: This can be done very simply with built-in stuff in Python that is probably completely missing the point of what your teacher wants you to do... :) I would say that Python is a poor choice for such assignments, but I feel it's more accurate to say that such assignments are a poor choice for a real world that has languages like Python ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult without knowing which parts of Python you have been taught so far, but here are some steps that may help

```
>>> ['The Boy','1:34','Let go','4:21','Wherever to', '5:30'][::2]
['The Boy', 'Let go', 'Wherever to']
>>> ['The Boy','1:34','Let go','4:21','Wherever to', '5:30'][1::2]
['1:34', '4:21', '5:30']
>>> zip(['The Boy', 'Let go', 'Wherever to'], ['1:34', '4:21', '5:30'])
[('The Boy', '1:34'), ('Let go', '4:21'), ('Wherever to', '5:30')]
```

You should use some variables instead of repeating the list over and over of course

Answer (score 2):

- Start with an empty list for the result
- Loop over a variable *i* starting from zero, going to the length of the input, counting by twos
- Extract the i-th value and the value at i+1
- Put them in a tuple
- Add the tuple to the result list
- Repeat

Actual code left for homework ;-)